# how to optimize multiple objective functions in genetic algorithm toolbox

Tags: optimization, matlab, genetic-algorithm

I have optimized single objective function in GA toolbox, but how do I optimize more than one objective functions?

For example I need to optimize the following set of objective functions:

```
f1 = x(1)^2 - 2*x(1)*x(2) + 6*x(1) + x(2)^2 - 6*x(2);
f2 = x(2) + x(3)*x(4);
f3 = x(4)^2 - x(5);
```

*Note: above functions are some how linked to each other therefore variables are also interconnected*

1. How these functions to be represented either in `.m` file or some other way?
2. I am worried whether these interlinked functions affect the variables, because I need only single optimized values of variables `x1` to `x5`.

Answer (score 0):

The image for the fitness function for the genetic algorithm has to be a totally ordered set. Usually when computing these things we are dealing with real numbers (or computer representations of those using floating point). The easiest way to get something like this to work is to compute each of `f1`, `f2` and `f3` then combine the results of these functions to make a new objective function. If you do that then you are only optimizing over the one objective function again, at least from the point of view of the programming side of things this should be useable via the same interface as before.. Perhaps the most difficult thing to do is to find the best way of combining the functions.